# ASP.NET Core 2.1 SignalR is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

This is my chat javascript

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chathub").build();

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = msg;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("Messages").appendChild(li);
});

connection.start().catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("Send").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var message = document.getElementById("Message").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This is the error I get when I run the page with my chat input:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: signalR is not defined
>       at chat.js:3

line 3 in `chat.js` is:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chathub").build();
```

I downloaded the `SignalR` client library from Visual Studio Add Client Side Library. What I have now is a file called `jquery.signalR.js` and it is the **ASP.NET SignalR Javascript Library 2.4.0.**

However, this error doesn't go away and I am unable to proceed for some reason.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I see your application is **ASP.NET Core** but you are using `jquery.signalR.js` which is actually for **ASP.NET MVC**. `SignalR` client for **ASP.NET Core** is `signalr.js` which is independent of `jQuery`. You can download the `signalr.js` for `ASP.NET Core` from [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr):

You can also download using Visual Studio Client Side **Library Manager (LibMan)** as follows:

- In **Solution Explorer**, right-click on the project, and select **Add >
  Client-Side Library.**
- In the **Add Client-Side Library** dialog, for Provider select `unpkg`.
- For Library, enter `@microsoft/signalr@latest`, and select the latest version
  that isn't preview.
- Must change **Target Location** to `wwwroot/lib/signalr` if it is anything else containing `@` in the path. Otherwise it would not download.

[image]

For more details: [Getting started with ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Hi, is there a way to get it without using npm? Do I have to install node js on my machine?

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/lib/signalr.js"></script>
    <script>
            const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl("http://localhost:56889/expeniSignalRServer")
                .build();

            connection.start().then(function () {
                console.log("connected");
            });
    </script>

This is how i am including in my page, still i am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: signalR is not defined

Comment: +1 Note that this package has since [been moved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58711826/5405967) from `@aspnet` to `@microsoft`.

Answer (score 1):

For my case i forget the order of sjgnalr.js and chat.js files.

```
  <script src="~/lib/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
```

My Mistake was as fllows:

```
  <script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
      <script src="~/lib/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
```

Cause I'm not care the order of js files so SignalR is not defined is usual.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong signalr javascript library. Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr, that's what worked for me.