# @aspnet/signalr vs @microsoft/signalr javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, signalr

What's the difference between @aspnet/signalr vs @microsoft/signalr javascript libraries?

Both seem valid for DotNetCore SignalR, both seem active. In some tutorials I find @aspnet/signalr and in DotNet docs they use @microsoft/signalr.

It seems a bit strange that there are 2 different official Microsoft libraries but couldn't find any explanation on what's different

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The package was simply [moved over](https://www.karltarvas.com/2019/11/05/aspnet-signalr-vs-microsoft-signalr.html) from `@aspnet` into the more broadly known `@microsoft`.

From now on, the correct package is `@microsoft/signalr`.

---

Looking at the version history for the two packages sheds light on the situation. Here are the latest releases for `@microsoft/signalr`:

- 3.1.0-preview2.19528.8 - 4 days ago
- 3.1.0-preview1.19508.20 - 21 days ago
- 3.0.0 - a month ago
- 3.0.0-rc1.19457.4 - 2 months ago
- 3.0.0-preview9.19424.4 - 2 months ago
- 3.0.0-preview8.19405.7 - 3 months ago
- 3.0.0-preview7.19365.7 - 3 months ago

And here are the ones for `@aspnet/signalr`:

- 3.0.0-preview6.19307.2 - 5 months ago
- 3.0.0-preview5-19227-01 - 6 months ago
- 3.0.0-preview4-19216-03 - 7 months ago

The move is further confirmed by the fact that the header for the `@aspnet/signalr` Github repository reads:

> [Archived] Incredibly simple real-time web for ASP.NET Core. Project moved to https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore

Which is the repository backing the `@microsoft/signalr` package.

Answer (score -3):

Look here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr
and here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr
@microsoft/signalr was started 6 months ago and its latest version is from 15 days ago while the latest @aspnet/signalr is from 8 months ago only

Comment: This answer adds no additional information to the already existing, accepted answer. Additionally the age of that last commits only tells a fraction of the story here.